# How to remove XML header for spring mvc @ResponseBody?

Tags: xml, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml")
@ResponseBody
```

resonpse xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml>
    <code>0</code>
    <msg>success</msg>
</xml>
```

however I the response I want like this

```
<xml>
    <code>0</code>
    <msg>success</msg>
</xml>
```

How to remove the XML header by annotation or XML config file?
Thanks.

**I have solved this problem**.

1. Use this XML Conventor

   ```
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
           <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
           <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
       </bean>
   ```
2. Config the Marshaller bean

   ```
   <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" id="marshaller">
   <property name="classesToBeBound">
       <list>
           <value>com.xx.entity.Message</value>
       </list>
   </property>
   <property name="marshallerProperties">
       <map>
           <entry>
               <key>
                   <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT"/>
               </key>
               <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
           </entry>
       </map>
   </property>
   ```

Comment: I have solved the problem by myself.

Comment: Well done. You should write the answer yourself so others with a similar question may benefit.

Comment: I mean as an actual answer not as an update to the question :-) It's difficult to find an answer that is hidden in the question. You can also earn extra rep

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm new at this。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I have solved this problem**.

1. Use this XML Conventor

   ```
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
           <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
           <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller"></property>
       </bean>
   ```
2. Config the Marshaller bean

   ```
   <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller" id="marshaller">
   <property name="classesToBeBound">
       <list>
           <value>com.xx.entity.Message</value>
       </list>
   </property>
   <property name="marshallerProperties">
       <map>
           <entry>
               <key>
                   <util:constant static-field="javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT"/>
               </key>
               <value type="java.lang.Boolean">true</value>
           </entry>
       </map>
   </property>
   ```

Comment: +1 Good job. Now you can mark it as answered after a period of time.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot you can create your own subclass of `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` and customize marshaller:

```
@Configuration
class XmlConfiguration {
    @Bean
    Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter() {
        return new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter() {
            @Override
            @SneakyThrows
            protected void customizeMarshaller(Marshaller marshaller) {
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

(`@SneakyThrows` is from lombok)